# How do I step through Cordova code when the app starts?

Tags: debugging, cordova, web-inspector, step-into

When I debug a Cordova app what I constantly do is step through its code inside Chrome's WebInspector. In order to be able to do this, however, I have to wait for the device to become ready in `chrome://inspect/#devices` (only then can I click on the appearing link for the started app). But if I do this the inspector will not halt on breakpoints if I am not quick enough. How do experienced Cordova developer tackle this issue?

Comment: I am no expert, but would like to make a suggestion. You could add an **alert** statement at the start of the device ready function. This will stop the script from running and then you could use your chrome for inspecting the APP there on. e.g `yourDeviceReadyFunction() { alert("I am ready!"); ....<your next statement> };`

Comment: Good point! I will use this suggestion henceforth as long as there is no clean way :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to frank's comment I just found GapDebug which offers [instant debug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/learning-center/user-guide/) and, thus, comes close to what I deserve.