# How to debug cordova web application _startup_ code

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, cordova

How to debug some javascript code executing **on the start** of cordova (phonegap) app? E.g. on page load.

I can open chrome dev tools and set breakpoints, but it is too late - code is already executed. Are there any ways to pause app execution on its start, to attach chrome dev tools debugger?

GapDebug also doesn't catch it.

Comment: I had suggested a method to do the same. Have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046814/how-do-i-step-through-cordova-code-when-the-app-starts#comment44477454_28046814).

Comment: alert works but it seems to be a hack/trick. Are there any other more proper they to do it?

Comment: I am not aware of any other method. That is what I could think of at the top of my hat.